# sem_init() causing SEGV

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, semaphore, segmentation-fault

I have the following code and it is being killed by a SEGV signal.  Using the debugger shows that it is being killed by the first sem_init() in main().  If I comment out the first sem_init() the second causes the same problem.  I have tried figuring out what would cause this sys call to cause a SEGV.  The else is not being run, so the error is happening before it can return a value. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thank you.

I removed the rest of the code that isnt being run before this problem occurs.

```
#define PORTNUM 7000
#define NUM_OF_THREADS 5
#define oops(msg) { perror(msg); exit(1);}
#define FCFS 0
#define SJF 1;

void bindAndListen();
void acceptConnection(int socket_file_descriptor);
void* dispatchJobs(void*);
void* replyToClient(void* pos);

//holds ids of worker threads
pthread_t threads[NUM_OF_THREADS];

//mutex variable for sleep_signal_cond
pthread_mutex_t sleep_signal_mutex[NUM_OF_THREADS];
//holds the condition variables to signal when the thread should be unblocked
pthread_cond_t sleep_signal_cond[NUM_OF_THREADS];

//mutex for accessing sleeping_thread_list
pthread_mutex_t sleeping_threads_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
//list of which threads are sleeping so they can be signaled and given a job
std::vector<bool> *sleeping_threads_list = new std::vector<bool>();

//number of threads ready for jobs
sem_t* available_threads;
sem_t* waiting_jobs;


//holds requests waiting to be given to one of the threads for execution
std::vector<std::vector<int> >* jobs = new std::vector<std::vector<int> >();

pthread_mutex_t jobs_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;




int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {

//holds id for thread responsible for removing jobs from ready queue and assigning them to worker thread
pthread_t dispatcher_thread;


//initializes semaphores
    if(sem_init(available_threads, 0, NUM_OF_THREADS) != 0){          //this is the line causing the SEGV
        oops("Error Initializing Semaphore");
    }

    if(sem_init(waiting_jobs, 0, 0) !=0){
        oops("Error Initializing Semaphore");
    }


//initializes condition variables and guarding mutexes
for(int i=0; i<NUM_OF_THREADS; i++){
    pthread_cond_init(&sleep_signal_cond[i], NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&sleep_signal_mutex[i], NULL);
}




if(pthread_create(&dispatcher_thread, NULL, dispatchJobs, (void*)NULL) !=0){
    oops("Error Creating Distributer Thread");
```

Comment: You're missing some `}`s and your indentation is poor.

Comment: Any missing }' are because I didnt post my entire code.  Any code past the point of the error I felt was unnecessary to post and would make this page unnecessarily long.  My poor indentation is from pasting my code into the window.  Alot of my formatting was lost.  It is properly indented in my file.

Comment: You are here because, when writing your code, you made a mistake. You then arbitrarily removed code when posting your question. How do we know which mistakes are real, and which were done during pasting? Create a complete, minimal testcase that exhibits _only_ the issue you're asking about, and _test that this is the case_ before posting.

Comment: P-T knew what my problem was within an hour of me posting this.

Comment: That doesn't magically fix the question. :) Learning to make a testcase, and getting used to it, is an invaluable skill not only in posing questions but also in performing your own debugging. P-T was able to answer because he spotted in your code a mistake that was clear despite the typos; there's no guarantee that this will be true next time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You declare pointers to your semaphores:

```
sem_t* available_threads;
sem_t* waiting_jobs;
```

but never initialize the memory.  The `sem_init` function is not expecting to allocate memory, just to initialize an existing blob of memory.   Either allocate some memory and assign these pointers to it, or declare the semaphores as `sem_t` and pass the address to `sem_init`.

Comment: This answer helped me just over six years later for a school assignment. Thanks!