# When does sem_init cause a segfault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, semaphore

I'm trying to figure out why my call to sem_init to initialize a semaphore is causing my program to segfault.

GDB tells me this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb7fb142e in sem_init@@GLIBC_2.1 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0xb7fb142e in sem_init@@GLIBC_2.1 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x080492ce in main (argc=3, argv=0xbffff9e4) at server.c:284
```

and when I try commenting out the line the program works fine. This is the offending code:

I put my semaphore in a struct with some other int variables

```
    struct stats {

    ...
    /* Semaphore should be put in the struct because when the process forks the
     * child will get a copy of the semaphore. Therefore it won't function as
     * intended. By putting it in the struct, it is located on the in the shared
     * mem
     */
    sem_t *sem;
};
```

and then I try to actually use it here

```
int shmid;
struct stats *statsPtr;

//Create or get the shared mem
if ((shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(struct stats), READ_WRITE_MODE)) < 0) {
    perror("shmget");
    exit(1);
}

//Attach the shared mem to process
if((statsPtr = shmat(shmid, 0, 0)) == (void *) -1){
    perror("shmat");
    exit(1);
}
//Init the semaphore
if((sem_init((statsPtr->sem), 0, 1))  < 0) {
  perror("semaphore init problem");
  exit(1);
  }
```

I've looked around and can't seem to find a good answer to what may be causing this. I found this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871276/sem-init-causing-segv), and the problem was they didn't allocate memory they just declared pointers but I think I have a different problem because I believe that I am allocating memory here:

```
//Create or get the shared mem
if ((shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(struct stats), READ_WRITE_MODE)) < 0) {
    perror("shmget");
    exit(1);
}
```

I also don't think that my previous function calls are failing because they are all wrapped in if statements. Does anybody have any suggests for what I may be able to try to resolve this issue/know why its happening?

Comment: before passing `statsPtr->sem` in as an argument, do you verify it is not a NULL pointer?

Comment: @ryyker Not explicitly but isn't that whats happening in the if statement trying to attach the address? If statsPtr was Null that would throw an error and exit, no?

Comment: @guribe94 _If statsPtr was Null that would throw an error and exit, no?_ -- no, not automatically. It would wait until you abuse it such as by trying to dereference it -- in which case a segfault is the common outcome ;)

Comment: `statsPtr->sem` is not a valid pointer. You need to declare that as just `sem_t sem` and pass `&statsPtr->sem` to `sem_init`.

Comment: for @kaylum's comment, also just declare `struct stats *statsPtr;` as `struct stats statsPtr;`  (as well as `sem_t sem`)

Comment: @ryyker I don't think the OP can do that. The OP wants to get the struct from shared memory so needs to use a pointer to store the shared memory location.

Comment: `shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(struct stats), READ_WRITE_MODE)` allocates enough memory for the `struct stats`, but that struct just includes space for a _pointer_ to a `sem_t`, not the entire `sem_t` struct.  Thus you might try: `shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(struct stats) + sizeof(sem_t), READ_WRITE_MODE)`.